# Getting cookies in XmlRpc Service

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat6, xml-rpc

I advise you it is gonna be a long post, since I don't really know whether what I want to do is possible and I even some problem defining my needs.
Basically, I was asked to extend an already `Apache XML-RPC Server` so that it is possible to have access to the cookies. I check out some documentation, and the service I need to expand has been creating following the official [Apache guide](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/server.html). My service looks like (sample code taken from the guide):

```
package org.apache.xmlrpc.demo;
public class Calculator {
  public int add(int i1, int i2) {
    return i1 + i2;
  }
  public int subtract(int i1, int i2) {
    return i1 - i2;
  }
}
```

The servlet we use to expose this service is the standard [org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.XmlRpcServlet](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/webserver/XmlRpcServlet.html) and we run on `Tomcat6`. That said, I need to modify `Calculator` in order to get some data from the cookies, like

```
public int add(int i1, int i2) {
  Cookie[] cookies = //how to do this?
  return i1 + i2;
}
```

Since we are using `Spring` I tried to modify `Calculator` to `Autowired` the request, like

```
package org.apache.xmlrpc.demo;
@Configurable
@Scope("request")
public class Calculator {

  @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;
  //...
}
```

but in this way I obtain an Exception

```
    Failed to invoke method searchFlights in class com.bravofly.bsa4.server.FlightsServiceXmlRpc: 
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? 
If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: 
In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

    org.apache.xmlrpc.common.XmlRpcInvocationException: Failed to invoke method searchFlights in class com.bravofly.bsa4.server.FlightsServiceXmlRpc: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:129)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.execute(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:106)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServerWorker.execute(XmlRpcServerWorker.java:46)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer.execute(XmlRpcServer.java:86)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:200)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.XmlRpcServletServer.execute(XmlRpcServletServer.java:112)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.XmlRpcServlet.doPost(XmlRpcServlet.java:196)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:202)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.currentRequestAttributes(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:231)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.access$0(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:230)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:245)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:1)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireUtils$ObjectFactoryDelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(AutowireUtils.java:178)
        at $Proxy73.getCookies(Unknown Source)
        at com.bravofly.bsa4.server.FlightsServiceXmlRpc.searchFlights(FlightsServiceXmlRpc.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:115)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.currentRequestAttributes(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:231)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.access$0(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:230)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:245)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:1)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireUtils$ObjectFactoryDelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(AutowireUtils.java:178)
        at $Proxy73.getCookies(Unknown Source)
        at com.bravofly.bsa4.server.FlightsServiceXmlRpc.searchFlights(FlightsServiceXmlRpc.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:115)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.execute(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:106)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServerWorker.execute(XmlRpcServerWorker.java:46)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer.execute(XmlRpcServer.java:86)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:200)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.XmlRpcServletServer.execute(XmlRpcServletServer.java:112)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.XmlRpcServlet.doPost(XmlRpcServlet.java:196)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:202)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Since I am sure I configured the `web.xml` properly by adding `RequestContextFilter`, the sentence

> Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web
>   request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving
>   thread?

in the exception makes me feel XmlRpcServlet runs (somehow) my Calculator Service in a completely isolated thread. If my guess is right, is there any way to get the request in my service? And if my guess is wrong, what am I doing wrong? Do you need also some configuration file (`web.xml`, `spring-context.xml`, etc) to better evaluate my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We came out to a workaround which may be useful to others and to ourselves again in the future, so I leave our solution as a reference tough we took the problem from another perspective. 
We realized `XmlRpcServlet` is actually a servlet (what a surprise) so we thought there should have been a `doPost` method to serve the requests. Looking at the source code of `XmlRpcServlet` infact there is a `doPost`, so we simply create our `CustomXmlRpcServlet` and override that method reading the cookies there, saving the desired value into server objects which were already at our disposal.

```
public class CustomXmlRpcServlet extends XmlRpcServlet
{

  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    //...
    super.doPost(request, response);
  }
  //...
  //Tough we do not have other customization, here it is possible to add additional method and/or override existing ones
}
```

We spent a couple of days trying to achieve our original goal, then a simple change of perspective solve our problem in a clean and easy way. Glad to be in a team!